# Update VBA Code to work on ACCDE file instant of MDE

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a VBA code in Access for some function for MDE file, I want to update the function to work on ACCDE file instant of MDE.
Where can i send my code to update it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't provide enough clarity to give you a definitive answer.  That said, I can make a guess at what might be your request.

If the issue is with declare statements at the head of your code you may need to add PtrSafe to them.

e.g., Instead of just:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
```

it would be

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
```

If however, you have people running different versions of office and VBA you'll want to encapsulate it in a precompiled (#) if statement to ensure backwards compatibility with earlier VBA versions.

e.g.,

```
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
#Else
   Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
#End If
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not answered My Question!

Comment: I refer you then to the first sentence in my answer.